# Exiting from async infinite loops

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, asynchronous, exit

I have initiated some async infinite loops in my WinForm application, but each time I am trying to break out of them, the program hangs up. I have read some similar topics where people suggested using CancellationTokens, but I am not able to adapt them to my needs. Here is the relevant part of my code.

```
static bool processStop = false;
static bool processStopped = false;

//Called once 
private async void ProcessData()
{
    while (!processStop)
    {
        await Task.Run
        (
            () =>
            {
                //Do stuff and call regular not async methods
            }
        );
    }
    processStopped = true;
}

//Button click handler to exit WinForm
btnExit.Click += (senders, args) =>
{
    processStop = true;
    //Programm hangs up here

    while (!processStopped);

    FormMain.Close();                
}
```

**Edited the code**
The variables are static.
The Close method is the default Close() method for Forms.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is caused by the code you are showing, also it's better if you could show us the code of Close method.

Comment: It sounds like you can't adapt this code either, why aren't you asking how to use cancellation tokens?

Comment: @AbdullahDibas Editted the code to make it more clear.

Comment: @Crowcoder Since I am studying multitasking now, I am not sure if CancelllationTokens are the finest answer for my problem. Also I am not familiar with CancellationTokens yet, so I asked for a more general answer. If it's possible.

Comment: how is `ProcessData()` called?

Comment: Cooperative Task Cancellation, using CAncellation Tokens are the recommended way to support cancellation in back ground operations. It is probably best to ignore 'infinite loops' of work while learning to use Tasks. Instead, focus on progress bars.

Comment: Like a regular method. `ProcessData();`

Comment: So you do not await it?

Comment: You should also show us your asynchronous method in Task.Run.

Comment: Most likely a transcription error but there is a typo in your sample. There is only one "p" in `while(!processStoped);`

Comment: The only reason I declared _ProcessData_ async is to allow me to use _await_ within it. I need to fetch and process some data in the background while my Form is running, but the CPU load of this task is huge and long-lasting which blocks the UI thread. That is why I am trying to run the async method to do all the work. The methods in the await call are not async. They do not have any particular tag.

Comment: @Crowcoder Don't mind that. It was just a typo I missed.

Comment: Try `await Task.Run(() =>{...}).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Jakub's comment is one piece of the puzzle which would solve your deadlock problem. However, if you only make that one change, I expect your code to work fine in Debug, but still freeze when you build your project in Release configuration (due to compiler optimising away the `while (!processStopped);` loop). So the second thing you need to do is to declare your `processStopped` variable as `volatile`, like so: `static volatile bool processStopped = false;`. Or, of course, you could re-engineer your solution from the ground up, and use `CancellationToken`s etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the call to `Task.Run` continues on the main thread. `processStop = true;` and `while (!processStopped);` execute synchronously one after the other. This doesn't let the `ProcessData` method continue its execution and a deadlock occures.
I see a couple of solutions:

- Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` with `Task.Run`:

  ```
  private async void ProcessData()
  {
      while (!processStop)
      {
          await Task.Run
          (
              () =>
              {
                  //Do stuff and call regular not async methods
              }
          ).ConfigureAwait(false);
      }
      processStopped = true;
  }
  ```

  This will cause the `ProcessData` to continue on a thread pool and you already use a thread pool by calling `Task.Run`, so it is not a great solution
- Wrap the whole process in `Task.Run`:

  ```
  static volatile bool processStop = false;
  static volatile bool processStopped = false;

  //Called once 
  private async void ProcessData()
  {
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
          while (!processStop)
          {
              ...
          }
          processStopped = true;
      });
  }
  ```

  This would require changing the form of the method passed to work with the loop in it.
- Make `ProcessData` a synchronous method to process CPU-intensive tasks and call it properly. `CancellationToken` would be the preferred way to cancel the task:

  ```
  private void ProcessData(CancellationToken token)
  {
      while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {                
          // do work
      }
  }
  ```

  And call it with this:

  ```
  Task processingTask;
  CancellationTokenSource cts;

  void StartProcessing()
  {
      cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
      processingTask = Task.Run(() => ProcessData(cts.Token), cts.Token);
  }

  btnExit.Click += async (senders, args) =>
  {
      cts.Cancel();
      try
      {
          await processingTask;
      }
      finally
      {
          FormMain.Close();
      }                
  }
  ```

Comment: You get points for appropriately using `volatile`, but you botched your last couple of lines of code: `FormMain.Close()` will never be called because `await processingTask` will throw an `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy It won't because the method completes gracefully, I don't use `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, but I just check for cancellation. Of course there could be other exceptions so it should be wrapped in `try{} finally{}` anyway.

Comment: Ah, but of course: I glanced over the `!token.IsCancellationRequested` check. It's rather unusual to see it used as part of `async Task` (as opposed to `async void`, where it makes more sense). Still, `try/finally` is definitely a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I used it just as an easy way to propagate the cancellation request asynchronously, there are other ways to do this.

Comment: @JakubDąbek Your answer was more than I could ask for. All three of your suggestions were detailed enough. I tried all of them, but only the first and the third one worked. It's fine though. I ended up using the CancellationToken which seems to be the "more professional" way of handling asynchronous tasks.   
Thank you Jakub and of course everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spin a bunch of tasks without blocking you can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Called once 
        private async Task ProcessData()
        {
            int count = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Run
                 (
                     () =>
                     {
                         this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                             label2.Text = (count++).ToString();
                             label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); }));
                         Thread.Sleep(100);
                     }
                 );
            }
            Debugger.Break(); //you will never see this hit at all
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           await ProcessData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I must not BREAK the ProcessData() on spot, because it uses the Serial Port and SQL queries.I have to stop it only when the all of the processing cycle is completed, else I won't be able to handle some errors I am already handling with my routines.

Comment: I see. You may want to spin up threads and use `Join()` to let them complete, and probably a semaphore gate to prevent too many from overwhelming the system.