# Async, await in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

On closing of my application I have to do some clean up activity and I have written something like this in ClassA.cs

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    Cleanup();
    base.OnExit(e);
}

private async Task Cleanup()
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    if (databaseInitialisation != null)
    {
        await databaseInitialisation.InitialiseDatabase();
    }
     databaseFile?.Dispose();
}
```

I have one more class ClassB.cs

```
public class DatabaseInitialisation : IDatabaseInitialisation
{
    private readonly string filterOptimisationPath;
    private readonly Task databaseInitialisation;

    private IDbConnectionFactory ConnectionFactory { get; }
    public async Task InitialiseDatabase() => await databaseInitialisation;

    public DatabaseInitialisation(string databaseFilePath, string filterOptimisationPath)
    {
        this.filterOptimisationPath = filterOptimisationPath;
        ConnectionFactory = new SqLiteConnectionFactory(databaseFilePath);
        databaseInitialisation = Task.Run(() => CreateDatabase(databaseFilePath));
    }
}
```

so now when I close my application, sometimes when cleanup is called execution of the program going from await is going to onexit method without executing the dispose method

Comment: You are not awaiting `Cleanup()` ...

Comment: Why are you running the GC and finalizers when your application is ending?  They all get cleaned up basically for free when the application ends.  Collecting expensive, and work that's only actually needed if you *aren't* about to end your application.

Comment: Outside that: Why not go for Disposables and ditch the GC stuff? Looks pretty overcomplicated to me.

Comment: @Fildor It wouldn't change the behavior of the program if they did, so why *would* they?

Comment: @Servy I meant using Disposable patterns for unmanaged resources and let the rest go its way naturally. Pretty much like you said in your comment, basically.

Comment: @Fildor I was referring to your first comment.  As for using IDisposable, it would appear they *are* using that where appropriate, but they're trying to handle the case of the application ending before the operation would normally finish, so they're trying to prematurely clean up,  They shouldn't need to call GC.Collect, but preventing the application from ending until the DB can be updated to a suitable place to close the application *is* a sensible thing to do.

Comment: @Servy Ah now I see. Yes, it seems so.

Comment: Hey Prasanna! Why do you want to call a method named `InitialiseDatabase()` in the application exit section?

Comment: @meJustAndrew The method is a bit of a mis-nomer.  Calling the method doesn't initialize the database, it simply returns an *already running task* of the database initialization.  In other words, they're trying to prevent the application from closing while the DB is currently in the middle of being initialized.  So the fix is just renaming it.

Comment: What behavior do you want/expect if that `InitializeDatabase` method fails?

Comment: See that solution... https://stackoverflow.com/a/46502718/15714806

Comment: Also - `Task.Run` in a constructor? I question whether that’s ideal. How about a non-async `Initialize` method and leave it up to the caller to choose whether or not to `Task.Run`?

Answer (score -1):

The root of your trouble is that you need to call an `async` method from a sync method, and you cannot make that method `async` because it's part of the GUI framework. The general advice here would be to make your calling method `async`, but since you can't, there are a few ways you can accomplish this:

### Option 1 -- `Task.Run`

Change your `OnExit` method to launch `Cleanup` on a thread pool thread and then synchronously wait for that using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to prevent deadlocks. Since this is only running once at shutdown, it should be fine, but launching background threads like this would not be recommended if this were a method that will run often as it could potentially lead to thread pool starvation.

```cs
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await Cleanup().ConfigureAwait(false))
        .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    base.OnExit(e);
}
```

### Option 2 -- `async void` and a `ManualResetEvent`

This approach avoids using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and launching on a thread pool thread, but any exception thrown in cleanup will cause the application to crash.

```cs
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    using var signal = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    Cleanup(signal);
    signal.Wait();
    base.OnExit(e);
}

private async void Cleanup(ManualResetEventSlim signal)
{
    if (databaseInitialisation != null)
    {
        await databaseInitialisation.InitialiseDatabase();
    }
     databaseFile?.Dispose();
    signal.Set();
}
```

You could also use one of the `Wait` overloads to include a timeout.

As a side note, in a GUI application like this, you should really be calling `.ConfigureAWait(false)` on every task you await that isn't being called directly from a GUI event. Not doing so risks deadlocks.

One caveat to both these solutions is that if your Cleanup method or anything in its call stack, both of these methods will deadlock, and in that case, another solution is needed.

Comment: This is just writing a solution that will deadlock anytime the operation in question accesses the UI thread, which is not unlikely to happen.  Cleanup of the UI itself is in fact *rather likely* to be interacting with the UI.

Comment: @Servy nothing about the code provided suggests that it will access the UI thread, but you are correct, that if it did, both of these solutions could deadlock.

Comment: We don't really know much of anything about what it's doing.  We know it's saving a bunch of data about the application.  Maybe in this case none of the information it needs to access is "owned" by the UI thread.  Maybe some of it it.  It would certainly be *reasonable* for some of it to be owned by the UI thread.  But to use a solution like this you need to *know, conclusively, that the UI thread isn't, and won't ever need to be, used*.  Saying that I can't say it is used isn't enough.  You need to be able to show that the UI *can't* be used if you want this solution to be valid.

Comment: @Servy I am not sure how I would prove that for an application I have never seen and never will... do you have another potential solution to their problem?

Comment: You *Don't block the UI thread* while running arbitrary asynchronous operations.  That you can't show that the code will work *is exactly why you should not be suggesting it as a solution*.  Doing so is irresponsible and just going to cause *extremely problematic* bugs in people using the solution.  Blocking like this is only valid when you can know, for sure, that nothing needs to, or will ever need to, interact with the UI thread.

Comment: I should have included that warning originally and edited the answer to include it. I think that coupled with the conversation here is enough for people to evaluate if it is appropriate for their situation or not. If you know of a better way to do this, I will be the first to upvote your answer.